# What does the right side of Hoeffding's Inequality tells me?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, mathematical-physics

The following is Hoeffding’s Inequality:

$P(|\nu - \mu| > \epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^2N}$

The left side looks like a probability notation but the right side becomes $2$ when the exponential part becomes very close to zero, then I would get $2$ for the right side. What does the number $2$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hoeffding's inequality tells that how likely $\nu$ is more than $\epsilon$ away from $\mu$. More specifically, it **upper bounds** the probability that $\nu$ is more than $\epsilon$ away from $\mu$. As you can see, the term in the RHS decreases as $\epsilon$ gets larger; that is, $\nu$ is more likely to be near $\mu$ and is less likely to be very distant from $\mu$.

The number $2$ here is just an upper bound. It states that the probability that $\nu$ is more than $\epsilon$ away from $\mu$ is not greater than $2$ when $\epsilon$ is very small. Actually, the upper bound $2$ here is quite loose here and it does not provide any insight. However, when $\epsilon$ gets larger, the upper bound can be much smaller than $1$, and in this case, we can use it to estimate the probability rather than computing the probability exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and could you please let me have an example of this? and do we actually use this?

Comment: @user122358 One example is to set $\epsilon = \sqrt{\ln N / N}$ and therefore the RHS is equal to $\frac{2}{N^2}$. That is, with probability at least $1 - \frac{2}{N^2}$, the value of $\nu$ would be in the range $[\mu - \epsilon, \mu + \epsilon]$.

Comment: Uhmm.... could you show me the step by step calculations? You set $\epsilon=\sqrt{\ln dfrac{N}{N}$ then the hoffding's inequality will look like

$P(|\nu - \mu|) > \sqrt{\ln dfrac{N}{N} \leq 2e^{-2(\sqrt{\ln dfrac{N}{N})^2N}$

Comment: @user122358 $-2\epsilon^2N = -2 \cdot \frac{\ln N}{N} \cdot N = -2\ln N$ and $2e^{-2\ln N} = \frac{2}{N^2}$.

Comment: How can I practically use it?

Comment: @user122358 See also this example. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/how-to-use-hoeffdings-inequality-to-find-a-confidence-interval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56485/discussion-between-user122358-and-yikai).